# How to get data from QML using QT to C++?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm new to this and I need your help. It is possible to get the speed from the "km/h" dial in a int variable. If the answer is yes can you show me how can I do this. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Here is my qml code.

[image: Here is my qml code.]

Comment: show your code as text

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access that property.  If you read through the documentation found https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html it shows an example that looks something like

```
QObject *obj = object->findChild<QObject*>("nameOfObj");
if (obj)
    obj->property("value").toInt();
```

Comment: The direction of dependency should be the other way around, the C++ layer should never access the QML layer, but the QML the C++. In this case, the dial should display a value provided as property of some C++ object.